# Verifying Linear Congruential Generator uniqueness for user ids

Tags: javascript, algorithm, proof-of-correctness

Id requirements:

- Short (# of characters for user to type)
- Allow as many ids as possible
- Seemingly random (so no one can easily guess user count by id)
- No mixed case characters (easier for user to type)
- No swear words generated

So I've chosen to go with a 6 character upper-case string, without vowels generated by a linear congruential generator sequenced on the user count. I learned about LCGs from wiki, and I would like to verify that my code is correct as I made up the coefficients in the LCG myself and would hate for there to be a collision of ids. I tried testing for collisions myself, but I ran out of heap space when storing the ids in a map after 2 million. I think the math checks out, but really would appreciate a second (or thousand) set of eyes. (Also not really that experienced with JS so if there's a more efficient way of swapping out the vowels, would love to know).

```html
// UserId generated from stored userCount key in redis, sequenced by a Linear
// Congruental generator, and stringified with a radix of 31 (all numbers and
// letters besides vowels = 10 + 26 - 5 = 31).
//
// The equation we will use to generate the sequence is:
// userVal = (a * userCount + c) % m + minVal

// To guarantee each userId is at least 6 characters, we need:
// minVal = 31^5 = 28629151
//
// To guarantee that our userId is at most 6 characters, we need:
// log31(minVal + maxVal + 1) = 6
// => 31^6 = minVal + maxVal + 1
// => maxVal = 31^6 - minVal - 1 = 858874529
//
// So our LCG needs to have:
// 1) m < maxVal
// 2) m and c relatively prime
// 3) a-1 is divisible by 4 if m is
// 4) a-1 is divisible by all prime factors of m
//
// m = 858062848 = 2^16 * 13093
// c = 1
// a = 3351809 = 2^8 * 13093 + 1
//
// This means we can support 858062848 unique userIds (>850 million).
// If we ever cross that amount, it will be a good problem to solve :)
this.getUserId = function(){
    var userCount = Spark.getRedis().incr("unique-id:user");

    var a = 3351809;
    var c = 1;
    var m = 858062848;
    var minVal = 28629151;

    var userVal = (a * userCount + c) % m + minVal;

    return userVal.toString(31)
        .toUpperCase()
        .replace(/A/g, 'V')
        .replace(/E/g, 'W')
        .replace(/I/g, 'X')
        .replace(/O/g, 'Y')
        .replace(/U/g, 'Z');
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to store the Id's in a map and if you do so, it will definitely run out of heap space after few million entries. Try bringing in databases for rescue if you really have to store them. Since all your `a, c, m ,minVal` are fixed, you have a unique userID for every `userCount`.  You can have this information at the client side and generate the `uniqueUserId` based on that without storing them in your system.

Comment: I *don't* need to store the id's in a map. I simply was saying when I tested the function to make sure no ids were duplicated up to 850mil, I ran out of space storing them in a map to check. I have since test by checking the next occurence of an id (one at a time), and it comes out as expected (the period, m). "Since all your a, c, m ,minVal are fixed, you have a unique userID for every userCount" - that's exactly what I was asking for verification on though. I think the values I chose guarantee uniqueness for the period, but I wasn't positive.

Comment: replace all "phishing" aliases; `1LI` and `0O` as well .you already do some, but users won't know which

Comment: also you might want to do more sanitize the output, even without vowels, there can be phrases and leet that offend, remember calculator tricks like `58008`? and far worse ones like `B1TCHY` or `FY0M0M`

Comment: Hmm dandavis, thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the conditions you have cited in your code for the linear-congruential generator are sufficient to ensure that the sequence is of maximal length. However, I believe this does not guarantee that the resulting random numbers have good statistical properties. There are some "preferred" choices of the LCG parameters which give good statistical properties (e.g. low correlation amongst groups of consecutive numbers), which are tabulated in Numerical Recipes (Press et. al.). More detailed theoretical discussion is in Knuth's Art of Computer Programming.

Comment: Yeah I'm not super concerned about unevenly distributed "random" numbers. If someone really wants to figure out how many users there are by figuring out the sequence generator, it's not really an issue if they do. I just don't want it completely obvious (user 1=100000, user 2 = 100001 etc). It just would be terrible if my 45th million user got the same id as someone else.